# Continuity boundary conditions to find expressions for constants

Tags: calculus, boundary-value-problem

I have that

$$
\phi(r) = 
\cases{
A_1\frac{e^{-\kappa r}}{r} &\text{for } r>a \\
\frac{A_2}{r} +B_2 &\text{for }  0< r< a
}
$$

where $A_2 =  \dfrac{q_1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r}$

I need that both $\phi(r)$ and $\frac{d \phi(r)}{dr}$ are continuous at $r=a$, in order to determine the constants $A_1$ and $B_2$. How set up these boundary conditions?

---

I believe this is the correct way is to set

$$
\phi_{r>a}(a) = \phi_{0< r< a}(a)
$$

and

$$
\frac{d}{dr}\phi_{r>a}(a) = \frac{d}{dr} \phi_{0< r< a}(a)
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you mean $r>a$ in the first line of the function?

Comment: No, the first one was correct. I fixed it.

Comment: Okay. Also $\phi$ is undefined at 0. Did you mean on the second line $0<r\leq a$?

Comment: Oh, it should be $0<r<a$!

Comment: What value does the function attain at $r = a$, then? It should be defined at $a$ to be able to be continuous.

Comment: $r$ is the polar coordinate, and $r=a$ is the center of a spherically symmetric potential.

Comment: And $\phi=0$ at $r=a$ (center of the potential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $\phi$ is continuous if $\lim_{r\to a^-}\phi(r)= \lim_{r\to a^+}\phi(r) = \phi(a).$

So what you have is almost correct, you just need to clarify things a bit more, for example: since $\phi$ is clearly continuous on $(a,\infty)$,

$$\lim_{r\to a^+}\phi(r) = \lim_{r\to a^+}\phi_{r>a}(r) = \phi_{r>a}(a).$$

Comment: So $\lim_{r\to a^+}\phi(r) = \phi_{r>a}(a)$ and $\lim_{r\to a^-}\phi_{0<r<a}(a)$, right? So I just equate these two, and do the same with their derivatives? I should perhaps have been as technically correct as you show, but purely mechanically, I am going the correct way?

Comment: Essentially, yes. As your last comment indicated in the original post, you need to check that $\phi_{r>a}(a) = \phi_{r<a}(a) = \phi_{r=a}(r) = 0.$

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear in the original post, but the point of all this is to determine $A_1$ and $B_2$.